# Bert for QuestionAnswering input exceeds 512

Tags: bert, transformer, question-answering, huggingface

I'm training Bert on question answering (in Spanish) and i have a large context, only the context exceeds 512, the total question + context is 10k, i found that longformer is bert like for long document, but there's no pretrained in spanish so, is there any idea get around bert.

What i tried is:

```
from transformers import BertConfig
config=BertConfig.from_pretrained(BERT_MODEL_PATH)
config.max_length=4000 
config.max_position_embeddings=4000
config.output_hidden_states=True
model = MyBertModel(config)
```

but still gives me an error mismatch

> RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for BertModel:
> size mismatch for bert.embeddings.position_embeddings.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512, 768]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([4000, 768]).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The maximum input length is a limitation of the model by construction. That number defines the length of the positional embedding table, so you cannot provide a longer input, because it is not possible for the model to index the positional embedding for positions greater than the maximum.

This limitation, nevertheless, is not arbitrary, but has a deeper justification: in a vanilla transformer, the memory requirements are quadratic on the input length. Therefore, limiting such a length is necessary for the model not to need too much memory.

There are variants of the Transformer architecture that are designed to overcome the quadratic memory problem, like [Reformer](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.04451), [Linformer](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.04768), [Longformer](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.05150), [BigBird](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.14062). They, however, are not "compatible" with the Transformer weights, so someone would need to train one of those models in a masked language modeling task (potentially with multitask learning on the next sequence prediction task) in order to reuse their weights in your context.

Comment: Hi @ncasas do you have any idea about a metric for QA evaluation?

Comment: QA is not my field of expertise, so I recommend you take a look at the QA papers in `paperswithcode` ([link](https://paperswithcode.com/task/question-answering))